# Browser not adding authentication header being requested to do so by the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-chrome, basic-authentication, asp.net-core-middleware

I have an ASP.NET Core WebApi project that runs in IIS and supports NTLM and Negotiate as authentication methods throughout. I have a need to add basic authentication to one particular endpoint, so I created a middleware for it:

```
public class BasicAuthMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public BasicAuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IOptions<List<BasicCredential>> credentials)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/basicauthendpoint"))
        {
            var authHeader = (string)context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic "))
            {
                //Validate credentials here...
                await next(context);
                return;
            }

            context.Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = "Basic";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        }
        else
        {
            await next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the middleware order in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<BasicAuthMiddleware>();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    //Swagger stuff here
});

//Check if a particular header is in the request
app.UseCustomAuthMiddleware();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

The middleware is called as expected the first time and when there is no `Authorization` header, it returns with 401. The browser then displays the username/password dialog and I enter the credentials and click ok to resubmit.

The middleware is called again the second time and the `Authorization` header is still missing.

I'm using a similar solution as explained in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/384#issuecomment-410117400). But the username/password prompt keeps popping up as there is no `Authorization` sent by the browser.

Is this an issue with the browser or is it because I have additional authenticate methods setup?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstand your question. You code shared with us seems correct. The correct order should like below:

```
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseMiddleware<BasicAuthMiddleware>();

        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        app.Run();
```

---

In your scenario, it is invalid to add the header when accessing `/basicauthendpoint`, which is the expected behavior.

***Because the Web Server side cannot change the client's behavior of sending requests.***

#### Right way

1. When logging into the application, we can generate and manage cookies.
2. When accessing `/basicauthendpoint`, we can modify the current cookie, or add some content, so as to meet the authentication requirements.

Comment: What does this answer even mean? Here it is described that the server should return 401 with "WWW-Authenticate" in the response: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication. And that's what I'm doing.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Let me check agin. Will update later.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono By the way, pls share us your program.cs file, I need to check the order of your custom middleware.

Comment: The 'Startup.cs' is quite long and complex If you tell what particular middleware and in which order maybe I can narrow it down.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono app.UseMiddleware<BasicAuthMiddleware>();   This line of code can be two or three lines before and after.

Comment: Edited my answer. I add the middleware before `app.UseSwagger` because I want to secure the swagger endpoint with basic auth.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252069/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-ivan-mark-debono).

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono https://dotnetfiddle.net/qtON5t  Try this. If still not fixed, pls re-create a new sample without any sensitive for us, we will help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Because basic auth is terrible, there is no built in support in .net core. The "right way" to build it is to create a custom `AuthenticationHandler`. For example, you could authenticate your users via MS Identity;

```cs
public class BasicAuthOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions 
{
    public string Realm { get; set; }
    public bool AllowInsecure { get; set; }
}

public class BasicAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<BasicAuthOptions>
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> userManager;
    private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User> claimsFactory;

    public const string BasicAuthorization = nameof(BasicAuthorization);

    public BasicAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<BasicAuthOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock, UserManager<User> userManager, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User> claimsFactory) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
    }

    private static readonly Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (!Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var header))
            return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();

        var auth = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(header.First());
        if (!auth.Scheme.Equals("basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || auth.Parameter == null)
            return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();

        var buff = new byte[auth.Parameter.Length];
        if (!Convert.TryFromBase64String(auth.Parameter, buff, out var len))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Authorization code not formatted properly.");
            
        var credentials = encoding.GetString(buff.AsSpan().Slice(0, len));

        var separator = credentials.IndexOf(':');
        if (separator == -1)
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Authorization code not formatted properly.");

        var name = credentials.Substring(0, separator);
        var password = credentials.Substring(separator + 1);

        var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(name);
        if (user == null
            || (userManager.SupportsUserLockout && await userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user))
            || !await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("The username or password is incorrect.");

        var principal = await claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);
        var ident = principal.Identities.First();
        ident.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Amr, "pwd"));

        return AuthenticateResult.Success(
            new AuthenticationTicket(principal,
                Scheme.Name)
        );
    }

    protected override Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        if (!Request.IsHttps && !Options.AllowInsecure)
            Response.StatusCode = 421;
        else
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 401;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Options.Realm))
                Response.Headers[HeaderNames.WWWAuthenticate] = $"Basic realm=\"{Options.Realm}\"";
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then you can use authorization policies to choose which endpoints can be accessed via basic authentication. In parallel with other authentication schemes.